# Are there any functional disadvantages to disabling day/night cycle?

Tags: cities-skylines

I don't think it matters, but for reference I am playing the PS4 edition.

I am considering disabling the day/night cycle mode. If I do this will it have any negative effects on my game play.

As an example of the opposite, if I could somehow disable day mode so it was always night, then I would expect that the solar plant would never product electricity.

Is there anything like that for the opposite? i.e. won't do anything during the day.

Basically, I am looking for any reasons that might justify keeping the day/night cycle mode switched on.

EDIT: I am not asking about the effects on budget settings, so it is [not a duplicate of this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297117/day-night-mode-and-the-budget).

Comment: Do you have any of the DLC? One of the packs creates leisure specializations for your commercial zones that include nightclubs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Day/Night Mode and the Budget?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297117/day-night-mode-and-the-budget)

Comment: @Malco: No. I am not sure if the PS4 edition has any DLC yet... I could be wrong though

Answer (score 2):

Having now played with the day/night cycle switched off for a good while, I can say that there appears to be no functional disadvantages in terms of game play. The solar power plants continue to constantly provide electricity for example.

However, it is worth mentioning that there is one trophy that requires you to spend 1001 nights in the city. It is unclear from my research if this requires the day/night cycle to be enabled though.

Note, at the time of writing this there was no DLC available. I cannot say if future DLC will add in game features that require the day/night cycle to work correctly.

Comment: How does this affect businesses such as nightclubs if you specify a region policy as leisure.

Comment: @DavidYell: I don't know. I have done much yet in the way of commercial specialisations, I will update my answer when I get around to playing with that area further